# One play button is controlling all other buttons actions WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, button

Probably very simple but I'm having trouble finding out what bit of my code needs to be changed to make this work. My media bit looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0keGz.png]

When I click play on any of the buttons all the other three buttons change aswell.

```
        public void ButtonPlay1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = DataContext as PlayButton.SampleContext;

        if (context == null)
            return;

        context.IsPlaying = !context.IsPlaying;
    }

    public void ButtonPlay2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = DataContext as PlayButton.SampleContext;

        if (context == null)
            return;

        context.IsPlaying = !context.IsPlaying;
    }

    public void ButtonPlay3_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = DataContext as PlayButton.SampleContext;

        if (context == null)
            return;

        context.IsPlaying = !context.IsPlaying;
    }
```

There are my three different buttons button click events. I have a class which is a BoolToVisabilityConverter and also a class called PlayButton which just checks to see if the button is playing this is what is in the PlayButton Class:

```
    public partial class PlayButton : xamlNewAudit
{
    public PlayButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new SampleContext();
    }

    public class SampleContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isPlaying;

        public bool IsPlaying
        {
            get { return _isPlaying; }
            set
            {
                if (_isPlaying == value)
                    return;

                _isPlaying = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("IsPlaying");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

EDIT : Sorry for brief explanation, I just want it so when I click play on one of the buttons the other two stay paused.

EDIT : Xaml code for the buttons are;

```
            <Button x:Name="ButtonPlay" Height="45" Click="ButtonPlay1_OnClick" Margin="-2,0,57,60" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" />

                        <Image Source="Images/PlayButton.png" Visibility="{Binding IsPlaying, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}, Converter={Application:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                        <Image Source="Images/pauseButton.png" Visibility="{Binding IsPlaying, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Visible}, Converter={Application:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

This is the XAML code for the first button, the code is the same for the other buttons except the Click event links to a different method.

Comment: I think you may want to clarify your question.

Comment: can i have the xaml code of your buttons?

Comment: @Inisheer I have added edit at the bottom sorry for brief explanation.

Comment: @NeelBhasin Sorry, Added the code in the edit.

Comment: so you want to play any clip or something one at a time?

Comment: @NeelBhasin I just want to import 3 differnt sound clips and let people play and stop as they wish.

Comment: please check once the `OnClick` Event for other two

Answer (score 1):

You've got three `Button` controls. You need three different `IsPlaying` properties, one for each of the `Button`s. You need three different `Click` handlers that use the three different `IsPlaying` properties. Doing things the way you are, you'll also need three different `ControlTemplate`s that also use the three different `IsPlaying` properties.

---

UPDATE >>>

There are plenty of easier ways to fulfil your requirements. One such way would be to use a `ToggleButton` instead of a `Button`. Using this, you can forget about your `IsPlaying` properties and just use the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` value instead:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" />
        <Image Source="Images/PlayButton.png" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, 
ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}, Converter={StaticResource 
Application:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <Image Source="Images/pauseButton.png" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, 
ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Visible}, Converter={StaticResource 
Application:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You seem to have declared your `Converter` very strangely... did that even compile?

Comment: Is there an easier way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If your binding to IsPlaying is the same for all three buttons then all three buttons will change when IsPlaying changes. Easiest way to change that is to have a seperate IsPlaying property for each button.

Comment: I Added 2 more properties to the PlayButton class, so now they all point to different properties and nothing has changed.

Comment: Breakpoint the setters and getters and you'll be able to see what's going on- if your XAML is looking correctly at the different properties then maybe something's setting all three.